# Sub Domain created on parent AWS main Domain not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

[image]I need help to setup AWS Sub domain. I have tried lot of option but no luck.

I have main AWS domain (myDomain.com). I have created web application and deployed on Tomcat server with Apache proxy in front.

I can access my applications using URL myDomain.com/app

As per Client request, I need to change URL from myDomain.com/app to app.myDomain.com.

I have created sub domain (app.myDomain.com) under my main domain (myDomain.com) but I am not able to access my application using URL app.myDomain.com.

I tried to ping app.myDomain.com but it is saying Ping request could not find host app.myDomain.com. Please check the name and try again.

Both my parent Domain and sub domain share same IP

Please have a look at screen shot attached?

Comment: I have tested after few hours and It is working now. I am able to access URL using sub domain i.e app.myDomain.com. Is AWS system requires some time to reflect on application after doing setup in Route 53?

Answer (score 0):

Normally AWS takes some time to update their name servers and for the full DNS propagation to happen when creating a new subdomain mapping.

If its an update of a record set, it could also be the case even after DNS change propagation happens, web browser returns cached DNS entries.

Note: The TTL values you set is important here which tells how longer yo cache the DNS entries.